# How to save a file with express-formidable

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

Quick question from a NodeJs beginner:

I'm using [express-formidable](https://github.com/utatti/express-formidable) in order to upload files to my server. How do I save them? n_n'

Inspecting the variable that holds the file I have:

[image: vscode screenshot]

But I don't know what to do with it. I have checked some methods from `fs` and tried `writeFile` but of course it only writes `[Object object]`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the File here not a browser's File, just a common object, but looks like File.

for avoid out of memory, the file has already saved in a temporary folder

you can just do like this:

```
const {name, path} = req.files.input

fs.writeFileSync(name, fs.readFileSync(path))
```